# Javascript Regular Expression: Replace spaced substring from the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like `Hello @William Turner. how are you?` and would like to replace term `@William Turner.` by `<a href="www.williamturner.com">@William Turner.</a>`

So, the resulting string will be `Hello <a href="www.williamturner.com">@William Turner.</a> how are you?`

I have tried to do it using below code:

```
var text  = "Hello @William Turner. how are you?";
var username = "William Turner.";
var user_profile_html = "<a href="www.williamturner.com">@William Turner.</a>";

var regex = new RegExp("\\@" + username + "\\b", "g");
text = text.replace(regex, user_profile_html);
```

It is working fine when `username` has no space like `William, John` etc.

Please share your knowledge how I can achieve it?

------------------- Edit --------------------

Regular expression I have mentioned in above code is working fine as answer posted by @hallleron.
But, One thing I was forgot to mention term to replace has special character like `.` so it is become `William Truner.`

Regular expression I have used and mentioned by @hallleron is working fine for term without special character.

As mentioned by @DimitrisDamilos in comment I am looking for [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) as well.

Comment: Although, @hallleron has posted the right answer below, I think you will find very useful to know about this website: http://regexr.com/. I use it very often and it could have told you if your RegEx was wrong.

Comment: Thanks all for answer and comment. As per my last edit I got the solution and regular expression `var regex = new RegExp("\\@" + username , "g");` is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Actually your code is fine but the `user_profile_html` variable has `"` inside the string as well which is wrong, replace with `'`.

Here is a working fiddle with two methods:

```js
// METHOD 1:

var string = "Hello @William Turner how are you?"
var username = "William Turner";

var result = string.replace('@' + username, '<a href="www.williamturner.com">@' + username + '</a>');

console.log(result);


// METHOD 2:

var text  = "Hello @William Turner how are you?";
var username = "William Turner";
var user_profile_html = '<a href="www.williamturner.com">@William Turner</a>';

var regex = new RegExp("\\@" + username + "\\b", "g");
text = text.replace(regex, user_profile_html);

console.log(text);
```